Registry key is not deleting
can anyone assist i have this bat file from Autodesk the application uninstalls the software but not the registry key im using SCCM, so SCCM think the application is still install so it fails,  i have added the script (in bold) but its not removing the registry key, any advise?
".\image\Installer.exe" -i uninstall -q --manifest ".\image\ACD_2023_en-US\setup.xml" --extension_manifest ".\image\ACD_2023_en-US\setup_ext.xml" reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\UPI2{32B8960F-CDF8-3965-BBF6-7DF1E39824AA}" /f
Regards,
Registry key is not deleting.

You use a batch file in an SCCM Application for the uninstall right? (Or are you using a normal command line or a SCCM program for the Uninstall?) Did you check the Box "Run installation and uninstall programm as 32-bit process on 64-bit clients" in your Deployment Type? (In the "Programs" Section)?
